# AirWatch API Delete Application Failure

Tags: php, ios, api, airwatch

I am trying to use the AirWatch API to remove an app from an iOS device. The API documents (v9.1) has this limited info:
**Uninstall Public Application From the Device**
**Functionality** – Removes a public application from a device.
**HTTP Method** – POST
**API URI** – https://host/api/mam/apps/public/{applicationid}/uninstall
**Response Obtained** – NA
*The DeviceId is identified in the Request-Payload*

I can successfully list the "apps" on the device via the AirWatch API **Retrieve Application Details From the Device** url *https://host/api/mdm/devices/{id}/apps? page={page}&pagesize={pagesize}* and identify which **applicationid** I want to remove (for example app ID = 22504).

However, the problem is that I get the error:
*"ErrorCode":404,"Message":"Application not found or user does not have access to it."*

Well I **KNOW** that it's there after AirWatch reported it to me so that isn't the problem. And the documentation assumes that it will just **work** as it doesn't list any error possibilities.

Anyone have any suggestions? The AirWatch API documentations not very good. . . . and some of it is wrong or has errors.

Comment: One thing I have found out that ISN'T addressed in the AirWatch api PDF documentation is this:

`Uninstalls the specified public application from a device.


Overview


Endpoint URL:

https://cn705.awmdm.com/api/mam/apps/public/{applicationid}/uninstall



Accept MIME Types:

application/json;version=1

application/xml;version=1


URL Parameters

Name Description Type 

applicationid The application Id. Int32 `

Comment: So, the XML or JSON request payload must be set to **version=1** whereas alot of the api specifies **version=2**.

This DOES allow the api call to work-without error. HOWEVER, it doesn't uninstall the app. .

Comment: Does anyone have a working example (php, python, or any other) for this API call??

Or does anyone know if this AirWatch API works?